# Invoke jenkins from screwdriver.cd

Tags: screwdriver-cd

I have configured screwdriver.cd cluster in local machine. Able to create pipeline and invoke few commands that run npm commands.

The idea we started exploring screwdriver is to connect our existing jenkins jobs to better show in good UI like screwdriver which provides feature called "Pipeline". I tried to add jenkins section in screwdriver.yaml as below.

```
jenkins:
  enabled: EXECUTOR_JENKINS_ENABLED
  options:
    jenkins:
      host: http://jenkins.local
      port: 8080
      username: admin
      password: <<<<<
```

But the pipeline execution failed with below error.

14:17:39
$ echo "ValidationError: "jenkins" is not allowed"; exit 1
14:17:39
ValidationError: jenkins is not allowed

Does screwdriver really allows to invoke external jenkins or we need to create jenkins via docker for every job execution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Screwdriver supports Jenkins as an executor via [`executor-jenkins`](https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/executor-jenkins) For usage see Jenkins section at [API Configuration documentation](https://docs.screwdriver.cd/cluster-management/configure-api#configuration)